# How to enable SSL connection on MySQL server in Windows

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

How do I enable SSL on MySQL server in Windows? I have downloaded OpenSSL but don't know how to get it work in Windows since all the commands are in UNIX shell. help anyone?

Comment: perhaps a user name as well... :P

Comment: this question seems better suited to serverfault.com, and here is a duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/783861/enabling-ssl-in-mysql-when-using-windows-as-a-server-and-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the OpenSSL website, there is a page for binary packages:
http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

I think that is what you want for Windows.

I can't say how good it will work. Also please clarify what you you want to do. You cannot "create SSL for MySQL in Windows". Do you want MySQL to have SSL encrypted connections perhaps?

Comment: i downloaded the exe from the above link you gave but the i followed the steps for windows until step 6 and got stock in here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-create-certs.html. i dont have a shell command line to continue on.

Comment: In windows, it's called a command prompt. Press, Win+R. Then type cmd followed by Enter. You should be familiar with the CLI of your OS. The commands on that page are different for Windows. Since you are doing some server work, why not use a real server OS, like FreeBSD or Debian?

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP has it in xampp\PHP\extras\openssl

Comment: what's XAMPP? is this answer related to the question at all?

Comment: @knocte: What is XAMPP?
XAMPP is the most popular PHP development environment
XAMPP is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and Perl. The XAMPP open source package has been set up to be incredibly easy to install and to use. (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html and then the links on the right hand side.

To work with openssl in Windows - locate where it is and then go Start > Run > (type) CMD

Type: cd PATH_TO_OPENSSL_FOLDER
Type: openssl ..... commands here .....

It will all depend on if you are purchasing an SSL certificate or creating a self signed one. Self signed are free and simple but purchasing one is deemed more secure / trusted.